# Meaning of a expression in the movie ad astra

Tags: cinema

There is one sentence in the movie ad astra confusing me about its meaning.
"Some times I see myself from outside. Smile. Present a side"
What does present a side mean?
I thank so much if anybody could help me.

Comment: In BrE we have the idiomatic [*There's no **side** to him*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20side%20to) (he's not arrogant / pretentious). There's also [*to have the **front** to do something*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german/front) (be cheeky / arrogant enough to do it), but I suspect that one might derive from ***effrontery***, rather than being a closely-related "visible facet / viewing angle" metaphoric usage.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the movie, but it sounds like this person is talking about showing themselves in an attractive way.

In photography, each person is said to have ["a good side"](https://www.marieclaire.com/beauty/news/a14637/good-side-bad-side/)-- the optimal angle from which to photograph them. So to "present a side" is to show yourself at an angle as if you're being photographed.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a reference to people having a "best side" when it comes to being photographed, [this lifehacker post](https://lifehacker.com/find-the-good-side-of-your-face-to-instantly-look-bet-1450741116) tells you how to find yours.

The idea of the quote is that, if you "see yourself from the outside", you are in a similar position to someone taking your photograph. "Smile, present a side" is an instruction that a photographer might give to their subject so the speaker is illustrating how they feel when they "see themselves from the outside".

Comment: So can it be meant as: to take a gesture?

Comment: @Habib Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "take a gesture".  I (and I believe @PlutoThePlanet) think that "Smile. Present a side" is just an ironic imitation of a professional (possibly papparatzzi)  photographer's patter. The speaker is making fun of his own statement about "seeing himself from the outside" and of his sense of his own importance.